# How to use Using Response.Transmit()

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

Here is a piece of my code:

```
if (objTbl.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Call-Details-Report-" + startDate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + ".csv";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");

    bool commaRequired = false;
    if (this.chkNET_NETWORKID.Checked)
    {
        Response.Write("Network ID");
        commaRequired = true;
    }
    if (this.chkNET_NETWORKNAME.Checked)
    {
        if (commaRequired)
        {
            Response.Write(",");
        }
        Response.Write("Network");
        commaRequired = true;
    }
}
```

In the above code *objTbl* is my datatable. I read the data from data table and write it to response and get the file for download.but I'm getting an error while I try to download huge files.

Insufficient memory during execution of program. I heard that `response.transmit`. Can solve this problem but how?

Comment: How big is "Huge"?  And where are you getting this error?  On the web server?  From a client browser?  From a client application?

Comment: When do you call the Response.Transmit() method? Seems like you code piece is missing some vital information.

Comment: @RQDQ from a client broswer and file size is about 180 mb

Comment: @Xharze sorry i updated the question plz check

Comment: @Jay - the above code appears to write at most "Network ID,Network".  It looks like you're missing a significant amount of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TransmitFile Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP response output stream, without buffering it in memory.

like this :

```
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ym.jpg");
        context.Response.TransmitFile(context.Server.MapPath(@"~/ym.jpg"));
        context.Response.End();
```

Comment: ok...but mine is a data table so how to go about writting it??

Comment: @Jay save it to file first. and then transmit the file

Comment: okk..i just have a doubt ,does response.write write the content to memory?is dat wats causing memory exception

Comment: response.writefile is for displaying a files contents, it requires a file to read from. Response.write simple writes text to the page.

Comment: but if i write data to file then all the files dat i download will be collected in the server system

Comment: @Jay - You asked how to use Reponse.Transmit() - this is how.

Comment: And one more thing , i'm getting this issue on only certain servers only, any particular reasons for that??

Comment: @RQDQ i'm just clarifying my doubts....its good 2 understand anything before using it

Comment: @Jay it coult be memory sizes or current free memory sizes in servers - also it can always be configurations problems.... its hardly to say ....